# student portal in sharepoint 2010 - design questions

Tags: 2010

i am trying to develop a student portal with FBA where students will login with credentials given to them and they will see a page which is customized to them.

I intend to create workflows, enable them download docs and also submit docs via this mini site for each student.

my question is around how to develop the secure pages that the students see.

what each student will see will be different based on his discipline and the courses he has registered for. this means that the content will basically be dynamic..

my question is how  best to develop this.

1) should i use web parts and based on his id, pull in data that is relevant to him?

2) he will have access to some lists too and this authorization will be done by the admin.
. how can i search through all the lists that he is to have access to and pull the links to them into a "links" webpart?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me, I'd let the designers determine what data the student should see, then you as the developer expose it however you need to.  If you have the Enterprise version, you could use audience targetting to assist with content visibility here too.

You'll want to use the content query web part to aggregate the links into a consolidated web part.  This requires the publishing infrastructure to be enabled.

Comment: thanks...does anyone have an example of the use of the content query web part in this scenario?